# ASP.NET AJAX Toolkit - CalendarExtender is reset on Postback

Tags: asp.net, calendarextender

I have an ASP.NET page that has two input elements:

1. A TextBox that is ReadOnly. This TextBox is the TargetControl of a CalendarExtender
2. A DropDownList with AutoPostBack=true

Here is the code:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr><td colspan="2">Date:</td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="2">
    <asp:TextBox ID="dateTextBox" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" />
    <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="datePicker" runat="server" Format="MM/dd/yyyy" OnLoad="datePicker_Load" TargetControlID="dateTextBox" />
  </td></tr>

  <tr><td colspan="2">Select an Option:</td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name:&nbsp;</td>
    <td><asp:DropDownList ID="optionsDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  
      OnLoad="optionsDropDownList_Load" 
      OnSelectedIndexChanged="optionsDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" 
      DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID" />
  </td></tr>

  <tr><td><asp:Button ID="saveButton" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="saveButton_Click" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

When the DropDownList posts back, the date selected by the user with the datePicker is reset to the current date. In addition, if I look at the Text property of dateTextBox, it is equal to string.Empty.

How do I preserve the date that the user selected on a PostBack?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The fact that the text box is read only appears to be causing this problem.  I duplicated your problem using no code in any of the bound events, and the date still disappeared.  However, when I changed the text box to ReadOnly=False, it worked fine.  Do you need to have the textbox be read only, or can you disable it or validate the date being entered?

EDIT:  OK, I have an answer for you.  According [to this forum question,](http://forums.asp.net/p/1429400/3198408.aspx) read only controls are not posted back to the server.  So, when you do a postback you will lose the value in a read only control.  You will need to not make the control read only.

Comment: Downvoting because I believe that @taeda's answer is the true answer to this problem.

Answer (score 12):

Certainly you must do as others have already suggested: set `readonly` field dynamically rather than in markup, and make sure you are not accidentally resetting the value in `Page_Load()` during postbacks...

...but you must also do the following inside `Page_Load()`, because the `CalendarExtender` object has an internal copy of the date that must be forcibly changed:

```
if (IsPostBack)  // do this ONLY during postbacks
{
    if (Request[txtDate.UniqueID] != null)
    {
        if (Request[txtDate.UniqueID].Length > 0)
        {
            txtDate.Text = Request[txtDate.UniqueID];
            txtDateExtender.SelectedDate = DateTime.Parse(Request[txtDate.UniqueID]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me. I tried making my textbox readonly=false and enableviewstate=true with no success. But when I manually set the calendar control's selected date to the textbox date, everything is just fine and working properly.

Answer (score 3):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txt_sdate.Text = Request[txt_sdate.UniqueID];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the textbox contents remembered after the postback and still keep it as readonly control, then you have to remove the readonly attribute from the markup, and add this in the codebehind pageload:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    TextBox1.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the issue is making use of Request.Form collections. As this collection has values of all fields that are posted back to the server and also it has the values that are set using client side scripts like JavaScript.

Thus we need to do a small change in the way we are fetching the value server side.

C#

```
protected void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string date = Request.Form[txtDate.UniqueID];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your datePicker_Load is setting something and not checking if it's in a postback. That would make it happen every time and look like it was 'resetting'.

Answer (score 0):

In stead of setting ReadOnly="False", set Enabled="False".  This should fix your issue.

Comment: Doesn't work as far as I can see - you still lose the value in the disabled field on postback.

Answer (score 0):

@taeda's answer worked for me. FYI, if someone uses `enabled = "false"` instead of `readonly = "true"` wont be able to use that answer, because `Request[TxtDate.UniqueId]` will throw a null exception.

Answer (score -1):

It is not a problem of Preserving,after **setting** `readonly = true` the value of the particular textbox doesn't be returned back to server
so

Use `contentEditable="false"` and **made** `readonly = false`

that would prevent value is being entered other than Calendar Extender selection also returns the value of the Text box back to the server