# Date selected from calendar control doesn't change in Textbox at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, asp.net-ajax, datetimepicker

I have to save date selected from  ajax calender control,when i select date from ajax calender control it shows in textbox,but when i save this date i got the previous value of date not the cureently selected value,i have written this code on btnsave_Click event

my .CS code is as follow:

```
protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime bdate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtBirthDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
}
```

my .aspx code for calender control:

```
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBirthDate" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"  CssClass="Txtprop" ></asp:TextBox>
    <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="calDOB" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtBirthDate" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" ></cc1:CalendarExtender>
</td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not set the property **ReadOnly="true"** on your TextBox.

`If TextBox's ReadOnly property is "true", postback data won't be loaded e.g it essentially means TextBox being readonly from server-side standpoint (client-side changes will be ignored). If you want TB to be readonly in the "old manner" use`

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("readonly","readonly")
```

as that won't affect server-side functionality.

For more information follow [StackoverflowAnswer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957129/asp-net-ajax-toolkit-calendarextender-is-reset-on-postback)   or [TextBox Readonly](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASP.Net-AJAX-CalendarExtender---Get-selected-date-from-ReadOnly-TextBox.aspx)
 problem.

Comment: it's ok.I like to improve myself.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set the date time format in .cs file itself. 
Look here 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: :Hi,thanks for your reply but dateformat is not an issue here...i am not getting calender selected date in my text-box at runtime

Answer (score 0):

before `<asp:Content>` add this line

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

After `<asp:Content`>  add

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this set the CalendarExtender's SelectedDate in the textbox.Text data = change to whatever it is in the textbox and it will stick. Setting SelectedDate sets the textbox field at the same time.

Easy fix example

```
'protected void txDate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
        txDate_CalendarExtender.SelectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txDate.Text);
}'
```